# autofac instance initialization notification

Tags: autofac

Is there a way to determine when Autofac has completed an initialization of an instance?
You may need it if you have Lazy dependencies, or you inject dependencies via properties.

Possible solution might look like this:

```
public class Component : IKeepMeInformed {
    private readonly IOtherComponent otherComponent;

    public class Component(Lazy<IOtherComponent> otherComponent) {
        this.otherComponent = otherComponent;
    }

    void IKeepMeInformed.InitializationCompleted() {
        // Do whatever you need with this.otherComponent.Value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly tied to Lazy components, but Autofac exposes events that lets you hook into the lifetime of instances. Listening for [the OnActivated event](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OnActivatingActivated) will enable you to do stuff immediately after an instance have been created. E.g.:

```
builder.RegisterType<OtherComponentImplementation>().As<IOtherComponent>()
    .OnActivated(e => InitializationCompleted(e.Instance));
```

*Update*: actually, in the context of your `Component` class, you should "know" when the instance is initialized. It will be whenever you access the `Lazy<>.Value` property first.

Comment: Thanks. I know there is such mechanism. I don't like changing registration details for each component, which needs such initialization. Therefore, I want to have interface-based solution.

Comment: The exact scenario is this: component (ICommand) take a another component (ViewModel) and subscribes to PropertyChanged event of it. Naturally, command should subscribe to event once it becomes available, which would usually be done in constructor. In my case where is a circular dependency, and ViewModel is not available in the constructor. Thus, I want Autofac to inform the component, when its construction is completed.

Comment: But isn't the lifetime of your command instance also controlled by the ViewModel? e.g. created in the VM constructor? Or do you envision that the command also is somehow created through the container?

Comment: The command is injected into any ViewModel that needs it through the container.